# flutter doesn't show icon image in splash screen android 12

Tags: android, flutter, splash-screen, android-12, flutter-packages

I want to set a splash screen for android 12 in flutter

I used [flutter_native_splash](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash) package but it doesn't show my icon

I added it to the `pybspec.yaml` file:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flutter_native_splash: ^2.2.8

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  
flutter_native_splash:
  color: "#ffff00"
  image: assets/splash.png
  android_12:
    image: assets/splash.png

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/
```

and created a separated file `splash.yaml`:

```
flutter_native_splash:
  color: "#ffff00"
  image: assets/splash.png
  android_12:
    image: assets/splash.png
```

the I ran this command `flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:create --path=splash.yaml`

it change the background color but it doesn't change the icon

I read the doc of the package and read [this](https://flutter%20pub%20run%20flutter_native_splash:create)  but I found nothing

Comment: Can you share the rest of your pubspec.yaml file? You did not show the section for assets.

Comment: I shared it I added assets too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking over your pubpsec.yaml file, under the assets key, you put the same key (a folder called assets).

```
 # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/
```

I would try and rename your assets directory to something else to make sure there isn't a problem there.

Also, since I do not know what your assets directory contains or where in your project it is located, I would try and explicitly add your splash image in the pubspec.yaml:

```
 # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
      assets:
        - images/splash.png
```

**Make sure your assets directory is located in the correct place**

[Documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/assets-and-images)